# How to draw a trapezoid shape of an image in qml?

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, polygon

I want to draw a trapezoid in qml with image inside the trapezoid image as a cropped image.

Comment: You probably want an OpacityMask.

Comment: yes. kind of. I have shared the solution as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it through Canvas.
Here is my solution:

```
Canvas {
    id: canvas
    anchors.fill: parent

    property string imagefile:"qrc:/myImage.png"
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(757,0);
        ctx.lineTo(1163,0);
        ctx.lineTo(1486, 1080);
        ctx.lineTo(434, 1080);
        ctx.lineTo(757,0);
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip();

    }

    onImageLoaded:{
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.scale(1/Screen.devicePixelRatio,1/Screen.devicePixelRatio);
        ctx.drawImage(canvas.imagefile,0,0,1920,1080);
        ctx.scale(Screen.devicePixelRatio,Screen.devicePixelRatio);
        canvas.requestPaint();
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {

        loadImage(canvas.imagefile);
    }
}
```